# Why does Apache load the PHP module from PATH instead of the one in httpd.conf?

Tags: php, apache

I have installed Apache (2.4.29) and configured it to use PHP 7.1.8 which is located at C:\php-7.1.8:

```
LoadModule php7_module "c:/php-7.1.8/php7apache2_4.dll"
LoadFile "c:/php-7.1.8/php7ts.dll"
LoadFile "c:/php-7.1.8/libeay32.dll"
LoadFile "c:/php-7.1.8/ssleay32.dll"
LoadFile "c:/php-7.1.8/libssh2.dll"

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html

SetEnv PHPRC C:/php-7.1.8/
PHPIniDir "C:/php-7.1.8"
```

I also have installed PHP 7.2.0 in C:\php7. This is also the value which is in the windows PATH system variable.

Browsing to a page with phpinfo() in it shows me that the loaded php.ini is from c:\php-7.1.8, but the PHP version used is 7.2.

Does the value of the PATH variable override the LoadModule directive in httpd.conf?

Comment: yes, in Windows PATH not so much overrides, as it is what is taken into account, since local environment uses what you set in the system. In windows 10 you can prioritize PATH paths, in earlier versions just replace the value in PATH.